# Text property not changing?

Tags: c#, text, properties

What is happening is, even though the questionNr is set to 1, it's not changing the .Text properties of ans1-4, as well as the questionLabel. Any help would be appreciated. Also as a sub-question, is it possible to do something along the lines of if(ans1.Clicked = true)?

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    int pointCounter = 0;
    private SoundPlayer _soundPlayer;
    int questionNr = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer("song.wav");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.amazon.com/Chuck-Seasons-One-Five-Blu-ray/dp/B007AFS0N2");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
    }


    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void muteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (muteButton.Text == "Mute")
        {

            muteButton.Text = "Unmute";
            _soundPlayer.Stop();
        }

        else
        {
            muteButton.Text = "Mute";
            _soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
        }
    }

    private void playButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ans1.Visible = true;
        ans2.Visible = true;
        ans3.Visible = true;
        ans4.Visible = true;
        playButton.Visible = false;

    }

    public void question()
    {
        if (questionNr == 1)
        {
            questionLabel.Text = "What is Chuck's full name?";
            ans1.Text = "Charles Irving Bartowski";
            ans2.Text = "Charles Richard Bartowski";
            ans3.Text = "Charles Luke Bartowski";
            ans4.Text = "Zachary Strahovski";
        }

    }

    private void ans1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ans2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ans3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ans4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you calling `question()`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, do I have to call this? If so how

Comment: In my humble opinion I think you should read a tutorial on C# first and then come back to stack overflow...

Comment: Ofcourse you have to call it. The only thing that will be automatically called is the default constructor. So just pu the line "this.question();" inside of the contructor after _soundplayer for example...

Comment: Yes, you need to call it. Try putting the line `question();` in your `Form_Load` function.

Comment: Call `this.question();` after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Oh thank you very much, it worked, I'm not too familiar with C# and coming from C only makes thing more confusing (for me personally)

Comment: @SzymonZmudzki Same logic in C as well.  You create a `function` and you have to call the `function` for what is in it to occur.  The difference would be if setting the question parameters was part of an `Event Handler` like a button click.  Then you would not need to call it because the `Event Handler` would take care of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Form where you invoke the `question()` method. First call that method from where you need.
eg: FormLoad/Button click etc..Then try

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer("song.wav");
        question();
    }
```

It's good if you put a break point in your Form Load event and see how your code executed.Then you'll get an idea about the flow of your code.